# Why the article ordering does not follow the date?

Tags: joomla-3.x

Recently I want to change the order of my article.

I set the Blog Layout Options -> Article Order -> Most recent first Date for Ordering -> Created However, it does not follow the date to order my articles.

After that, I tried to set it as Article Manager Order, and re-order it by changing the ordering numbers. However, it still does not work.

However, it does work when I set it as Title Alphabetical.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome aukk123, please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback.

Comment: It should actually work. Hard to say without looking at it. Could be any overrides anywhere? Or are you sure the changes you do and what you are looking at in the front-end are the same?